# What should I do to set a variable in function by user in __name__ == "__main__" in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,3,5]
cheak = []
def duplicate(any_list):
    for things in any_list:
        if things not in cheak:
            cheak.append(things)
        else:
             pass
    return cheak

if __name__ == "__main__":
    duplicate(my_list)
```

I want the user to tell which list to remove duplicate, how can I do with this.

Comment: Do you know how to do this outside of the ˋ__main__ˋ guard?

Comment: can you add excepted input and output, so we can give you better solutions.

Comment: you can do this is in one line,  ```cheak = list(set(my_list ))``` it removes all the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    my_list = [1,2,3,4,3,5]
    duplicate(my_list)
```

You have to assign my_list before passing it to duplicate. Outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you need:

```
def duplicate(any_list):
    cheak = []
    for things in any_list:
        if things not in cheak:
            cheak.append(things)
        else:
             pass
    return cheak

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = [1,2,3,4,3,5]
    duplicate(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is what you need:

```
def duplicate(any_list):
    '''remove duplicates from list'''

    cheak = []
    for things in any_list:
        if things not in cheak:
            cheak.append(things)
    return cheak

def mainFun():
    my_list = [1,2,3,4,3,5]
    print(duplicate(my_list))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainFun()
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Note also that the `else` condition is not required.

A faster implementation and more Pythonic for what you want to do:

```
def duplicate(any_alist):
    '''remove duplicates from list'''

    return list(set(any_alist))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written two types of solution.

1. The `duplicate` function uses a local variable (`func_loc_cheak`)(in function scope) and return the content of this local list.
2. The `duplicate_glob` function uses a global variable (`cheak_global`) and it doesn't return anything because you can use this global variable without variable assignment.

I have added several print to see the behaviors and differences between the functions.

**Code:**

```
cheak_global = []


def duplicate_glob(any_list):
    for things in any_list:
        if things not in cheak_global:
            cheak_global.append(things)


def duplicate(any_list):
    func_loc_cheak = []
    for things in any_list:
        if things not in func_loc_cheak:
            func_loc_cheak.append(things)
    return func_loc_cheak


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Test lists.
    my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5]
    my_other_list = [8, 9, 0]

    result = duplicate(my_list)
    print("After first function call: {}".format(result))

    result = duplicate(my_other_list)
    print("After second function call: {}".format(result))


    print("Content of 'cheak_global' before function call: {}".format(cheak_global))

    duplicate_glob(my_list)
    print("Content of 'cheak_global' after first function call: {}".format(cheak_global))

    duplicate_glob(my_other_list)
    print("Content of 'cheak_global' after second function call: {}".format(cheak_global))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
After first function call: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
After second function call: [8, 9, 0]
Content of 'cheak_global' before function call: []
Content of 'cheak_global' after first function call: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Content of 'cheak_global' after second function call: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 0]
```